# Do secretomotor neurons activate for secretory cells due to the absence or presence of water and electrolytes? Why?

Tags: neuroscience

I read this passage in a book called *Integrative Action of the Autonomic Nervous System* by Wilfrid Jänig. In this book, he states

> Reflex pathways involved in the regulation of secretory cells and/or local blood vessels (arterioles) have been much less explored than enteric reflex pathways that are involved in regulation of motility. This applies to the organization of the reflex pathways connected to the mucosa and mucosal blood vessels as well as to their coordination with the reflex pathways that are integrated into the regulation of motility. Activation of secretomotor neurons stimulates epithelial cells to secrete chloride ions into the intestinal lumen, taking with them sodium ions and water. The physiological stimuli that induce a reflex activation of the secretomotor neurons are mechanical stimulation of the mucosa (shearing stimuli) and chemical stimuli (e.g., glucose or proton ions). The most important activator of the reflexes is the absorption of water and electrolytes by nutrient transporters. For example, glucose transport involves the Na+-transporter and each molecule of glucose is accompanied by Na+, counterions and water. Absorption of 100 grams of glucose is accompanied by 1.8 liters of water (Furness 2006). The purpose of the secretomotor reflexes in vivo is therefore to preserve whole-body fluid balance. The intraluminal stimuli triggering secretion appear to be the same as those causing enteric motility reflexes in the intestine. The stimuli activate the IPANs via enterochromaffin cells (EC) in the mucosa, which release 5-HT and excite the IPANs, or possibly by other cells releasing CCK or motilin (Figure 5.13). The IPANs excite enteric neurons synaptically by release of acetylcholine and substance P. Intraluminal toxins, such as cholera toxin, lead to pathological activation of secretomotor neurons. This overwhelms the fluid-balance role of the reflexes, causes copious fluid loss and, if unchecked, death, because the fluid ultimately comes from the circulation. Secretomotor reflexes elicited by intraluminal physiological stimuli are always paralleled by enteric vasodilator reflexes mediated via the enteric neurons.

I am specifically confused by the sentence

> The most important activator of the reflexes is the absorption of water and electrolytes by nutrient transporters.

Is he saying that the secretomotor neurons are triggered by the absorption of water and electrolytes? Or is he saying the absence of absorption triggers the reflex?

Comment: I read the text without having looked at your specific question, and I was confused in much the same way. I'm looking forward to the answers.